# Не подключается повторно к базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

В программе база данных MYSQL подключается несколько раз к нескольким страницам. Проблема в том, что подключение успешно лишь для первой страницы, для других страниц выходит ошибка "Нет подключения к БД".

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in Z:\home\shop\www\include\db_connect.php on line 8
Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\shop\www\include\db_connect.php on line 10
Нет соединения с БД Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

```html
<?php
defined('myeshop') or die('Доступ запрещён!');
$db_host  = 'localhost';
$db_user  = 'root';
$db_pass  = '';
$db_database = 'dbshop'; 

$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass, $db_database);

mysql_select_db($db_database,$link) or die("Нет соединения с БД ".mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET names cp1251");
?>
```

Comment: См. [CREATE USER Resource-Limit Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html#create-user-resource-limits), параметр *MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS*, и [Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections), одноимённый глобальный параметр.

Comment: Заодно объясните, как так получается - в логах один юзер, а в коде другой...

Comment: А также почему вы используете устаревшее 10 лет назад расширение `mysql`.